# How to get the leader feature importances in h2o automl pysparkling water

Tags: h2o, sparkling-water

i am using spark standalone cluster and running h2o pysparkling in it.
I am unable to find the function for getting the leader feature importances. please help

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pysparkling import *
import h2o
from pyspark import SparkFiles
from pysparkling.ml import H2OAutoML
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkApplication').getOrCreate()

conf = H2OConf()
hc = H2OContext.getOrCreate(conf)

def xgb_automl_features_importance(data, target_metric):
    # Converting DataFrame in H2OFrame
    hf = h2o.H2OFrame(data)
    sparkDF = hc.asSparkFrame(hf)
    # Identify predictors and response
    y = target_metric
    aml = H2OAutoML(labelCol=y)
    aml.setIncludeAlgos(["XGBoost"])
    aml.setMaxModels(1)
    aml.fit(sparkDF)
    print('-----------****************')
    print(aml.getLeaderboard().show(truncate=False))
```

Answer (score 0):

The fit method on `H2OAutoML` returns the leader model. Each model in SW has the method `getFeatureImportances()` returning Spark data frame with feature importances.

```
model=aml.fit(sparkDF)
model.getFeatureImportances().show()
```

Comment: getFeatureImportances() - this function is returning None object!

Comment: Can you share leaderboard for your particular run?

Comment: `Model Details
===============
H2OXGBoost
Model Key: XGBoost_1_AutoML_1_20220813_162406_08ae0501887b
Model summary
Number of Trees: 30
Training metrics
RMSLE: 1.9279105523758344
Nobs: 10.0
RMSE: 11.10180165558726
MAE: 9.5
MeanResidualDeviance: 123.25
ScoringTime: 1.660388047538E12
MSE: 123.25
R2: -2.734848484848485
Cross validation metrics
RMSLE: 1.9279105523758344
Nobs: 10.0
RMSE: 11.10180165558726
MAE: 9.5
MeanResidualDeviance: 123.25
ScoringTime: 1.660388047546E12
MSE: 123.25
R2: -2.734848484848485`

Comment: The XGBoost model should have feature importances available. Only StackedEnsemble models return `None` on `getFeatureImportances()` method.

You can try that on other models from leaderboard.

```
    aml.fit(sparkDF)
    models = automl.getAllModels()
    models[1].getFeatureImportances().show()
    models[2].getFeatureImportances().show()
```